# Vulkan validation error when I try to reset a commandPool after vkQueueWaitIddle

Tags: vulkan

I have a small Vulkan program that runs a compute shader in a loop.

There is only one commandBuffer that is allocated from the only commandPool I have.

After the commandBuffer is built, I submit it to the queue, and wait for it to comple with `vkQueueWaitIddle`. I does indeed wait for a while in that line of code. After that, I call `vkResetCommandPool`, which should reset all commandBuffer allocated with that pool (there is only one anyways).

```cpp
...

vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);
        
{
    VkSubmitInfo info = {};
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    info.commandBufferCount = 1;
    info.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;
    vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &info, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
}
vkQueueWaitIdle(queue);

vkResetCommandPool(device, commandPool, VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT);
```

When it tries to reset the commandPool the validation gives me the following error.

```
VUID-vkResetCommandPool-commandPool-00040(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: -1254218959
- Validation Error: [ VUID-vkResetCommandPool-commandPool-00040 ]
Object 0: handle = 0x20d2ce0b718, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; |
MessageID = 0xb53e2331 |
Attempt to reset command pool with VkCommandBuffer 0x20d2ce0b718[] which is in use.
The Vulkan spec states: All VkCommandBuffer objects allocated from commandPool must not be in the pending state
(https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.176.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandPool-commandPool-00040)
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x20d2ce0b718, type: 6, name: NULL
```

But I don't understand why, since I'm already waiting with `vkQueueWaitIdle`. According to the [documentation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.176.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#commandbuffers-lifecycle), once the commandBuffer is done executing, it should go to the `invalid` state, and I should be able to reset it.

Here's the relevan surrounding code:

```cpp
VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
beginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr;

for (i64 i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
{
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

    vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, pipeline);
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_COMPUTE, pipelineLayout,
        0, 2, descriptorSets, 0, nullptr);

    uniforms.start = i * numThreads;
    vkCmdUpdateBuffer(commandBuffer, unifsBuffer, 0, sizeof(uniforms), &uniforms);
    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT, 0,
        0, nullptr,
        1, &memBarriers[0],
        0, nullptr);

    vkCmdDispatch(commandBuffer, numThreads, 1, 1);

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0,
        0, nullptr,
        1, &memBarriers[1],
        0, nullptr);

    VkBufferCopy copyInfo = {};
    copyInfo.srcOffset = 0;
    copyInfo.dstOffset = 0;
    copyInfo.size = sizeof(i64) * numThreads;
    vkCmdCopyBuffer(commandBuffer,
        buffer, stagingBuffer, 1, &copyInfo);

    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);
        
    {
        VkSubmitInfo info = {};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
        info.commandBufferCount = 1;
        info.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;
        vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &info, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    }
    vkQueueWaitIdle(queue);
    vkResetCommandPool(device, commandPool, VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT);

    i64* result;
    vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMem, 0, sizeof(i64) * numThreads, 0, (void**)&result);

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        if (result[i]) {
            auto res = result[i];
            vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMem);
            return res;
        }
    }
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMem);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a false positive. Are your layers updated to the latest?

Comment: There seem to be relevant a ticket at [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers#2756](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/issues/2756)

Comment: @krOoze I installed the Vulkan SDK last week. Thanks, that seems to be the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem. In `vkCmdDispatch`, I thought the paremeters specify the global size (number of compute shader invocations) but it's actually the number of work groups. Therefore, I was dispatching more threads than I intended, and my buffer wasn't big enough, so the threads were writing out of bounds.
I believe the validation layer wasn't giving me the right hints though.